# php -v showing 8.1 but composer unable to update

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm trying to update Laravel version of my dockerized app and since it requires PHP 8.1 or higher, I changed my image to 8.1 and also changed composer.json php requirement but when I run composer update it throws this error in the screenshot. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Can you show also your composer.json file?

Comment: _"I changed my image to 8.1"_ Meaning, you're using a different image? Or you installed 8.1 on top of your old 8.0 image and now you have both versions installed?

Comment: Also, please run `composer diagnose` and post the output.

Comment: After you change your image you need to rebuild it via the dockerfile and make sure you run `composer update` from within the updated image